# Cytoscape js error inside the styleSheet in Angular

Tags: angular, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape in my angular project, when i create a new cyto graph, in the styles i try to use the `"background-opacity"` attribute in one of my classes, but when i serve the project, after it compiles it throws an error in the console

```
ERROR in src/app/graph/graph.component.ts(101,5): error TS2322: Type '({ selector: string; style: { 'background-color': string; label: string; }; } | { selector: string; style: { color: string; "background-color": string; "background-opacity": string; "text-valign": string; label: string; }; } | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Stylesheet[] | Promise<Stylesheet[]>'.
      Type '({ selector: string; style: { 'background-color': string; label: string; }; } | { selector: string; style: { color: string; "background-color": string; "background-opacity": string; "text-valign": string; label: string; }; } | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Stylesheet[]'.
        Type '{ selector: string; style: { 'background-color': string; label: string; }; } | { selector: string; style: { color: string; "background-color": string; "background-opacity": string; "text-valign": string; label: string; }; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'Stylesheet'.
          Type '{ selector: string; style: { color: string; "background-color": string; "background-opacity": string; "text-valign": string; label: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Stylesheet'.
            Type '{ selector: string; style: { color: string; "background-color": string; "background-opacity": string; "text-valign": string; label: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'StylesheetStyle'.
              Types of property 'style' are incompatible.
                Type '{ color: string; "background-color": string; "background-opacity": string; "text-valign": string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Node | Edge | Core'.
                  Type '{ color: string; "background-color": string; "background-opacity": string; "text-valign": string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
                    Types of property '"background-opacity"' are incompatible.
                      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'PropertyValue<NodeSingular, number>'.
```

It shows the graph, but it keeps giving me an error. It goes away when i delete the property from the style sheet.
This is my cyto styelsheet portion

```
style: [
  {
    selector: 'node',
    style: {
        'background-color': 'black',
        label: 'data(id)'
    }
},
    {
      selector: '.count',
      style: {
        color: 'white',
        "background-color": 'black',
        "background-opacity": '0',
        "text-valign": 'center',
        label: 'data(id)'
      }
  },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        "text-margin-y": '-10',
        label: 'data(value)'
      }
  }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally just use the `background-color` property with `rgba(0,0,0,0)` to set the opacity, but cytoscape.js just accepts rgba, hex, color names and hue. Therefore, you can set the opacity with the `opacity` key:

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'label': 'data(id)',
        'background-color': 'black',
      }
    },
    {
      selector: '.count',
      css: {
        'color': 'white',
        'background-color': 'rgb(0,0,0)',
        'opacity': '0.5',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'label': 'data(id)',
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
        'text-margin-y': '-10',
        'label': 'data(value)'
      }

    }
  ],
  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n0'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n1'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n2'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n3'
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: 'n0',
          target: 'n1',
          arrow: 'triangle',
          value: '0->1'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n1',
          target: 'n2',
          arrow: 'triangle',
          value: '1->2'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: 'n1',
          target: 'n3',
          arrow: 'triangle',
          value: '1->3'
        }
      },
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: 'concentric',
    minNodeSpacing: 140,
  }
});

cy.ready(() => {
  cy.fit()
  cy.center()
  cy.$('#n1').addClass('count')
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape@3.10.1/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Even though i did this, the error keeps showing up
  `Type '{ color: string; 'text-valign': string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Node | Edge | Core'.
                  Type '{ color: string; 'text-valign': string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Edge'.
                    Types of property '"text-valign"' are incompatible.`

Comment: `Type '({ selector: string; css: { 'background-color': string; label: string; }; } | { selector: string; css: { color: string; 'text-valign': string; label: string; }; } | { selector: string; css: { label: string; 'text-margin-y': string; }; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Stylesheet[]'.`

Comment: Please add more code, I can't guess what you are doing wrong :D